# why 3.14 + 1.00 = 4.140000000000001 give more decimal value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var a=3.14+1.00;
document.write(a + "<br>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

output:
4.140000000000001

Every time when something adds to 3.14 either it is 1 , 2 , or 1.00 
it gives more decimal value ending with "1".

Comment: Those are not decimals, but floats

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: +1 just because I have not experienced this yet and because it links to an excellent explanation and external resources

Comment: Duplicate, but I just love this error.